# Use variable as key to parse json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a var, let's say

```
var product = "something"
```

I have a json file that looks like

```
{
   "something": [
     {
        "price": "2000"
     }
   ], 
....
```

I need to access "price" from "something", so I'm trying

```
data.product.price
```

and it gives me undefined.
I can easily get price value using data.something.price , but in my case it won't work because var product is dinamic value, so I need help with parsing my json, using my var as a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use square brackets here, and also, your `price` is inside an array so you need to access it using `[0]`

```
data[product][0].price
```

Here, I select `something` object using `data[product]` and later, to select the first object in the array, I used `[0]` and then I select `price` key.

```js
var product = 'something';

$.get('https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/596b31ce194a6c7f2b90406e', function(data) {
  console.log(data[product][0].price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```